# Convert a multiline dataframe cell into multiple row - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a multi-line cell in a pandas dataframe into multiple rows in the table

> ```
>   column1               column2    column3
> 0        1                    Hi      hello
> 1        2  some\nTest\nTo\nWork         hi
> 2        3                  Hiya  somewhere
> 3        4                             test
> 4        5               Another       test2
> 5        6                             test3
> ```

Given the above table I want my output to look like below:

> ```
>    column1               column2    column3
> 0        1                    Hi      hello
> 1        2                    some    hi
> 2        2                    Test    hi
> 3        2                    To      hi
> 4        2                  work      hi
> 5        3                  Hiya      somewhere
> 6        4                             test
> 7        5                  Another    test2
> 8        6                             test3
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 df.fillna('').set_index(['column1','column3']).stack().str.split('\n', expand=True).stack().unstack(-2).reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index()         
Out[1516]: 
   column1    column3 column2
0        1      hello      Hi
1        2         hi    some
2        2         hi    test
3        2         hi      To
4        2         hi    Work
5        3  somewhere    Hiya
```

Comment: The rows where column2 are Null are not being returned in the final dataframe

Comment: Weird. Can you share a sample of those rows? I can have a look.

Comment: I added more rows on my  sample... basically when I run your code, the cells in column2 without data get discarded.

Comment: It works now! Thank you!! can you please explain the code? what does stack().str.split do? and the two reset_index?

Comment: So, `set_index` basically sets the index on the columns which are not to be touched. `str.split('\n')` splits the column on `newline` char and creates new rows. It will be best if you run each command individually and check the behaviour for yourself. If the answer helped, please accept it too.

Answer (score 2):

Split on newline and "un-nest":

```
from itertools import chain

v = df.pop('column2').str.split('\n')  # if this doesn't work, try r'\\n'. 
df = (pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(v.str.len(),axis=0), columns=df.columns)
        .assign(column2=list(chain.from_iterable(v)))
        .sort_index(axis=1))

print(df)
  column1 column2    column3
0       1      Hi      hello
1       2    some         hi
2       2    Test         hi
3       2      To         hi
4       2    Work         hi
5       3    Hiya  somewhere
```

Comment: @coldspeed I am getting the following error: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: @Didier it looks like you have missing data in column2. Give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

df[['column1','column3']]=np.repeat(df[['column1','column3']].values(df['column2'].str.split('\n').str.len()),axis=0)
df['column2']=','.join(df['column2'].values.flatten()).split()
print(df)
  column1 column2    column3
0       1      Hi      hello
1       2    some         hi
2       2    Test         hi
3       2      To         hi
4       2    Work         hi
5       3    Hiya  somewhere
```

Comment: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable